# Karma Angular benchmarks

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm trying to convert a simple mocha/jasmine CoffeeScript test into workable benchmark:

```
beforeEach module('ngVendorMimeType')

beforeEach inject ($injector) ->
  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend')
  $http = $injector.get('$http')

afterEach ->
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
  $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()

describe 'should not match the request url', ->
  it 'should not alter the Accept', ->
    path = '/views/index.html'
    $httpBackend.expectGET(path, (headers) ->
      return headers.Accept == 'text/html'
    ).respond(200)
    $http.get(path, (
      headers: (
        'Accept': 'text/html'
      )
    ))
    $httpBackend.flush()
```

I have tried karma-benchmark without success, due to the fact that window object is not referencable. Is there a tool/framework that would help with doing that. My only expectations is that it runs through Karma has Angular test integration, optionally runs on PhantomJS and gives some output report.